# Image segmentation using python on google colab

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory, image-segmentation

I'm trying to segment the food parts of this plate into three different images using just opencv/ python libraries instead of deep learning techniques.
[This is the main food image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQDIr.png)
I tried applying mask on the BGR form of the image that we see when using opencv.

```
lower_blue = np.array([10, 50, 100])
upper_blue = np.array([110, 225, 225])
mask = cv2.inRange(orig, lower_blue, upper_blue)

result = cv2.bitwise_and(orig, orig, mask = mask)

#cv2_imshow(result)
plt.imshow(result)
```

I got this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okJ5K.png) where the most of the plate is black and only food is highlighted.
I then converted it back into
[RGB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HZsD.png)
I thought of taking the contours from the previous image.

```
lowerthresh = np.array([60,60,60])
higherthresh = np.array([250,250,250])
mask = cv2.inRange(convertedimage,lowerthresh,higherthresh)
mask.shape
```

Contours of image:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzkd5.png)

My main goal is to get the three food items into three different images.
Like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Cox.png) for example,
and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJLXD.jpg)

Basically to get cropped images of all the food.
But now it seems as though I didn't choose the right approach to this problem.
Is there any other way to solve this?

Update: I used used the hue channel in the HSV colorspace to mask the background of the image

```
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv
sample_h= rgb2hsv(rgb)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15,5))
ax[0].imshow(sample_h[:,:,0], cmap='hsv')
ax[0].set_title('Hue',fontsize=15)
ax[1].imshow(sample_h[:,:,1], cmap='hsv')
ax[1].set_title('Saturation',fontsize=15)
ax[2].imshow(sample_h[:,:,2], cmap='hsv')
ax[2].set_title('Value',fontsize=15);
plt.show()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5vFq.png)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(15,5))
im = ax[0].imshow(sample_h[:,:,0],cmap='hsv')
fig.colorbar(im,ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('Hue Graph',fontsize=15)

lower_mask = sample_h[:,:,0] > 0
upper_mask = sample_h[:,:,0] < 0.15
mask = upper_mask*lower_mask

red = rgb[:,:,0]*mask
green = rgb[:,:,1]*mask
blue = rgb[:,:,2]*mask

mask2 = np.dstack((red,green,blue))

ax[1].imshow(mask)
ax[2].imshow(mask2)
ax[1].set_title('Mask',fontsize=15)
ax[2].set_title('Final Image',fontsize=15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/636x0.png)

Comment: Have a look at the HSV colorspace (cvtColor(img, COLOR_BGR2HSV). Try thresholding in the S channel, as your background (the silver tray + cutlery) should show very dark there.

Comment: How much do you care about the semi-transparent liquid in the top right container ?

Comment: @nick I'm excluding the liquid for now.

Comment: Hello @nick, I tried working on it in the HSV colorspace. The cutlery part is dark and these results look much better. Thanks! Is there a way to separate these food parts into different images?

Comment: You can remove smaller gaps from the mask with `dilate` and `erode`. Then you can `findContours` and get the top level contours. If you need more help, please update your question with your current code.

Comment: @Rjj123: Using HSV should also give more consistent results for non-yellow foods (Green Jell-O anyone ? :D). Keep an eye on those reflections, though. For splitting the images: Have a look at the bounding boxes of the contours (````cv.boundingRect()````), then crop you image with those.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74822873/to-perform-segmentation-of-images-of-various-food-dishes